# How do I express a soundwave as a function?

Tags: integration, functions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have the soundwave of an A major chord and I am trying to use Fourier Transform on the soundwave to find the notes in the chord. Basically, using Fourier Transform on the wave function of the soundwave to find the amplitudes/volumes of the all the possible notes in the chord to determine which 3 are the loudest/of the highest amplitude. But to do that I need to turn my raw soundwave data into a function to plug into my Fourier Transform. SO how do I do that?

Comment: If you have functions corresponding to the notes that make the chord (A,C#,E), then the soundwave of the chord corresponds to the sum of these functions.

Comment: What you mean by " I have a soundwave..."? As a data sampled file? You need a file that contains the TIME samples and than execute the transform to get the FREQENCY domain. Sample rate and requisition period will provide the desired results.

Comment: @Moti I have a wav file of the soundwave of the A major chord

Comment: You need to convert it into a file that provides time values at a known sample rate. Once you have it you can run transformation to frequency domain. Try the question in the DSP exchange.